# Sumproduct Through Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm working on a script that currently applies a sumproduct formula across a large number of cells.

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS('Completion Data'!$A:$A,{Settings!E$5:E},'Completion Data'!$B:$B,$D2,'Completion Data'!$C:$C,"Completed"))=0,"Incomplete", "Completed")
```

What it does is it looks for the person's ID on a sheet called Completion Data and brings back the status. If the status shows as Completed it will return "Completed" as the value. "Incomplete" if it shows any other status.

It is also looking at the course code on Column A of the Completion Data tab. This can be any number of courses listed in Column E starting at row 5.

**What I'm currently doing:**

- I am using `.setFormula()` across the range of cells.
- I then use `SpreadsheetApp.flush();`
- I then copy and paste the values
- This process is repeated for a total of 5 columns. The only difference between the formulas is the column it references with the course codes on the settings tab.

**The problem:**

The process currently takes 12 minutes to complete on ~60K rows. This number will grow. Max 175K. I need this to be quicker because I worry it will timeout.

How can I reproduce this code in google script without the use of the formula or is this the only method to achieve this?

**Example Sheet**
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PFuww90NuMxT4b-kVqwcCooxLpSnaki7u9hATjZ7K78/edit#gid=2100307022

- Main Dataset - This will have ~70k lines but could be over 100K
- Completion Data - This will have ~70K lines but could be over 150K

**Clarification based on Community Comments**

- Because the sheet is so large I copy/paste these formulas. Every week I update the sheet to include any new people as well as new completion data, so I need to redo the formula application as well as the copy/paste

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide your current script, the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: The output is shown on the sheet I provided on the Main Dataset Tab, columns B through F. The input would be Column A of that sheet and then the data on the other two sheets. My script is simply applying the formula using ```.setFormula()``` and then I copy and paste.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is find a way to get the same result without using a formula. I'm hoping it would be faster than applying the formula and then copying and pasting. With all of the data I have it takes a very long time for the formulas to calculate.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected logic for achieving your goal, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your expected result and that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: I added some clarification to the post but essentially, I need to reapply the formula and each time I update the records on the Main Dataset and Completion data sheet. I update the records each week. Because the sheet is so large I copy/paste the values so that the sheet isn't slow which means I have to reapply the formulas each time I update the records. Hope this helps you understand.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your reply and your updated question. Can I ask you about the details of your current issue of my proposed script? Unfortunately, I confirmed that my proposed script could obtain your sample expected result. I apologize for this. First, I would like to correctly understand your current issue of my proposed script.

Comment: The expected result should be what my sample shows. The goal is to achieve the sample via script instead of formulas with the hope that it is faster than my method of adding formula and then copy paste.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, from `The expected result should be what my sample shows. The goal is to achieve the sample via script instead of formulas with the hope that it is faster than my method of adding formula and then copy paste.`, I cannot still understand your current issue with my proposed script. I'm worried that from your reply, my answer was not useful. In this case, I have to delete my answer. I think that this is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: When I could correctly understand your current issue of my proposed script, I would like to think of a modification point. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: @Tanaike... I just tested the script you had up and it worked. Can you repost it. It completed the task in 40 seconds!! That's amazing.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `@Tanaike... I just tested the script you had up and it worked. Can you repost it. It completed the task in 40 seconds!! That's amazing.`, I understood that your issue was resolved. So, I reopened my answer. Please confirm it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, from your provided Spreadsheet, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  // This is from your provided Spreadsheet.
  const obj = [
    { name: "Main Dataset", range: "A2:A" },
    { name: "Completion Data", range: "A2:C" },
    { name: "Settings", range: "E5:I" }
  ];

  // 1. Retrieve values and ranges from 3 sheets.
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const [sheet1, sheet2, sheet3] = obj.map(({ name, range }, i) => {
    obj[i].sheet = ss.getSheetByName(name);
    obj[i].range = obj[i].sheet.getRange(range + obj[i].sheet.getLastRow());
    obj[i].values = obj[i].range.getValues();
    if (i == 1) {
      // For "Completion Data" sheet.
      // Create an object for searching values.
      obj[i].values = obj[i].values.reduce((o, [a, b, c]) => {
        if (c == "Completed") {
          o[b] = o[b] ? { ...o[b], [a]: c } : { [a]: c };
        }
        return o;
      }, {});
    } else if (i == 2) {
      // For "Settings" sheet.
      // Transpose the retrieved values.
      obj[i].len = obj[i].values[0].length;
      obj[i].values = obj[i].values[0].map((_, col) => obj[i].values.map((row) => row[col]));
    }
    return obj[i];
  });

  // Create an array for putting into the destination range by follwoing your logic.
  const values = sheet1.values.map(([a]) => {
    if (sheet2.values[a]) {
      return sheet3.values.map(e => e.some(f => sheet2.values[a][f]) ? "Completed" : "Incomplete");
    }
    return Array(sheet3.len).fill("Incomplete");
  });

  // Put the values to the destination range.
  sheet1.sheet.getRange(2, 2, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

#### Testing:

When this script is run, the following result is obtained. It seems that this result is the same as your expected result in your Spreadsheet.

[image]

#### Note:

- This sample script is for your provided Spreadsheet. If you change the Spreadsheet, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.
- If the process cost of this script is high in your actual situation, it might be required to use Sheets API instead of Spreadsheet service (SpreadsheetApp).

#### references:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: I don't know how you do it but this is excellent. I tested it on the sample sheet I provided and it processed in ~40 seconds. That's a vast improvement compared to my 12+ minutes processing. I will apply this to my actual spreadsheet and let you know if I have any questions. Amazing work!

Comment: @DanCue Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. My sample script is for your provided Spreadsheet. If your actual Spreadsheet is different from your provided Spreadsheet, my proposed script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

Comment: Would you be able to add more comments throughout your code so I can understand what is doing what? I'm trying to figure out what part of the code loops through each of the columns.

Comment: @DanCue About your 2nd request of `Would you be able to add more comments throughout your code so I can understand what is doing what?`, I updated my answer.

Comment: I have to add columns to include the completion date for each Course. Should I amend this question or add a new one?

Comment: @DanCue About your new question of `I have to add columns to include the completion date for each Course. Should I amend this question or add a new one?`, I would like to support you. In this case, I would like to recommend posting it as a new question.

Comment: Will do. I'm trying to finish something up for work so I'm tied up tonight but I will post tomorrow and let you know. Thank you.